# How to include a backslash \ in the hexdump output format string?

Tags: hexdump

What I want to see:

```
$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '1/1 " %03o"'|tr ' ' '\\'
\360\237\230\200\012
```

What I tried:

```
$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\%03o"'
hexdump: bad conversion character %�

$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\%03o"'
hexdump: bad conversion character %%

$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\\%03o"'
hexdump: bad conversion character %\

$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\\\%03o"'
\\\\360\\\\237\\\\230\\\\200\\\\12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this example in the `hexdump` man page:

> ```
>        # hex with preceding 'x'
>        % echo hello | hexdump -v -e '"x" 1/1 "%02X" " "' ; echo
>        x68 x65 x6C x6C x6F x0A
> ```

it seems you can use `-e '"\\" 1/1 "%03o" '`

Ex.

```
$ echo hello | hexdump -v -e '"\\" 1/1 "%03o" ' ; echo
\150\145\154\154\157\012
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the right way. I didn't need the backslash in the format string itself (my bad ;) ), just in front of each output item.